# my downloaded .gz files have a dot and don't work properly

Tags: windows, downloads, curl, extension

I have downloaded, using curl, some .fastq files for genomic analysis, but they seem to be corrupted or something, they show a small dot after the extension (using Ubuntu terminal on Windows 10). Any ideas on this? generally redownloading fixes the problem.

[image: The extension dot!]

Thanks

Comment: What happens if you edit the file name and remove the dot?

Comment: The double quote (`"`), or whatever the "dot" character is, probably got there because of incorrect quoting in your `curl` command, so take a look at that for future downloads.

Comment: I found out this little symbol was added because i was lacking disk space and the files were partially downloaded.